# OpenSSL C#.NET Wrapper Error while DLL generation

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, openssl

I am on windows and I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express Edition. 
I downloaded the OpenSSL .NET Wrapper "openssl-net-0.4.4-src" and I tryed to compile it. 
I found two solutions : one for Visual 2005 and one for 2008. I chose the 2008 one, after converting it to 2010 environment. While converting, some components where not converted. 
And while compiling I got errors like some namespaces were not found. 
I found that the solution is using "using NUnit.Framework;" and i does not exist.

**Questions**

Is "NUnit.Framework" the problem ? if yes, should I download it and put a reference on it?
Or should I use directly Microsoft Visual C# 2008 to avoid the conversion?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it can't find NUnit.Framework, you should [download](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download) it. Using Visual Studio 2008 won't help with this - if you're missing an assembly, you're missing an assembly...

Comment: the 2008 solution contains 3 project cli, ManagedOpenSsl (contains the crypto library) and test (this project use NUnit.Framework ). I want to add some classes into the wrapper so i deleted the test project and tryed to generate the DLL of the ManagedOpenSsl one juste to check but my classes are not available ;s

Comment: @WolFSharp: If you don't need to build the test code, you shouldn't need NUnit.